# How does a pop (index) operation work in Python?

Tags: python

Below is a `pop()` operation of Python written in C.

```c
static PyObject *
list_pop_impl(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t index)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=6bd69dcb3f17eca8 input=b83675976f329e6f]*/
{
    PyObject *v;
    int status;

    if (Py_SIZE(self) == 0) {
        /* Special-case most common failure cause */
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, "pop from empty list");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (index < 0)
        index += Py_SIZE(self);
    if (!valid_index(index, Py_SIZE(self))) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, "pop index out of range");
        return NULL;
    }
    v = self->ob_item[index];
    if (index == Py_SIZE(self) - 1) {
        status = list_resize(self, Py_SIZE(self) - 1);
        if (status >= 0)
            return v; /* and v now owns the reference the list had */
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    Py_INCREF(v);
    status = list_ass_slice(self, index, index+1, (PyObject *)NULL);
    if (status < 0) {
        Py_DECREF(v);
        return NULL;
    }
    return v;
}
```

I understand that `pop(index)` takes `O(N)` time. But there's no `for` statement here.
It just returns `v`.

If `pop(0)`, does Python move all the pointers inside the list forward one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that at the C level, a `list` is an array of pointers to the objects contained in the list.

In the code above, it calls `list_ass_slice()` which literally just calls `memmove()` to relocate the pointers after the popped element.

From `Objects/listobject.c:list_ass_slice()`:

```
    if (d < 0) { /* Delete -d items */
        Py_ssize_t tail;
        tail = (Py_SIZE(a) - ihigh) * sizeof(PyObject *);
        memmove(&item[ihigh+d], &item[ihigh], tail);
```

The `O(N)` is a reflection of the time it takes to relocate (up to) `N` objects of `sizeof(PyObject *)` bytes.